# Spring H2 Embedded, при тестировании не найдены sql файлы

Tags: java, spring, h2

Я использую для теста репозитория такой стартовый код:

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    embeddedDatabase = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
            .addDefaultScripts()
            .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
            .build();
    jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(embeddedDatabase);
    personRepository = new PersonRepositoryImpl(jdbcTemplate);
}
```

Он должен создавать и инициализировать таблицы в H2. Но при запуске я получаю такую ошибку:

> org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.CannotReadScriptException:
>   Cannot read SQL script from class path resource [schema.sql]; nested
>   exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource
>   [schema.sql] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Как спринг пытается искать эти sql-файлы? У меня они находятся в директории проекта resources/sql. Почему спринг не заходит в нее?

Comment: покажите pom.xml или build.gradle

Comment: По умолчанию, файлы schema.sql и data.sql должны находиться в папке resources.

Comment: Если хотите изменить путь, то добавьте в application.properties следующее:
spring.datasource.schema=classpath:/sql/schema.sql
spring.datasource.data=classpath:/sql/data.sql